# Alternatives to command line unzip?

Tags: macos, terminal, script, zip

I've found that the command line `unzip` tool doesn't gracefully handle some of the files I'm unzipping: it makes a bunch of junk directories, and creates files whose resource forks aren't found.  (Perhaps they were created strangely.)

```
$ unzip -d NEW-DIRECTORY ZIP
```

Anyways, using `Archive Utility` is a start, because I can run the following and it is close (and it doesn't mess up my files):

```
$ open -a "Archive Utility" ZIP
```

But this does not allow me to specify a new directory for the contents!!  It automatically puts them in the current directory. :P

What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) has a beta version of their command line utility available on their [downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/theunarchiver/downloads/list).

Comment: +1 for suggesting `unar` without using it's name. ;)

Answer (score 12):

"The Unarchiver" is a great tool, and I highly recommend it, both the GUI and the CLI tools.

That said, my `unzip` command is

```
ditto -xk foo.zip target_dir
```

where 'target_dir' is the directory where I want the files to appear (and it can be '.' if you want them to unzip right there).

Note that 'target_dir' will be created if needed.

**Also note that `ditto` does not mind overwriting files, so use with care.**

ditto on Mac OS X is designed to preserve resource forks, etc. so it is my preferred method of unzipping files, especially because it ships with OS X by default.

Comment: Can't get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this extremely helpful answer to a problem I was having unzipping applications on another board from user patashnik:

unzip doesn't handle the embedded resourceforks in ZIP files created by the Finder. If you want to unarchive those files from the CLI, use ditto:

```
ditto -V -x -k --sequesterRsrc --rsrc FILENAME.ZIP DESTINATIONDIRECTORY
```

If you want to unpack the archive in the current directory, use . as DESTINATIONDIRECTORY

Answer (score 1):

7z can handle some oddly zipped files

`brew install p7zip
7z x weirdarchive.zip`

Answer (score 0):

you can use also:

- [yemuzip](http://www.yellowmug.com/yemuzip/)

and

- [stuffit-expander](http://www.stuffit.com/mac-expander.html) (not free)

Answer (score 0):

[Springy](http://www.springyarchiver.com/) is a very versatile unarchiver.  Shareware - and worth it to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install unar
```

and then:

```
unar foo.zip
```